# Audio encoding from 3gp to mp3 files in android

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

How can i convert my recorded audio files to mp3 format..so that

they can be played on any of the browser i already searched through the web to much

but did not get anything useful .

by default android is making a 3gp file using AMR_NB encoding.

Comment: By default, yes. But you can also tell `MediaRecorder` to generate e.g. an MPEG-4 container with AAC data. Refer to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html).

Comment: yes doing the same ran my media file on browser like mozilla, chrome  IE ON windows m/c and safari on mac m/c but not on mozilla on mac machine